# Why is var not incremented in this example?

Tags: java, multithreading

In below code I'm attempting to count the number of times the `execute` method is invoked but `count` is not incremented :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ThreadTest {

    @Test
    public void testThread() {

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter) {

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                es.execute(new FooWorker());
            }

            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println((count * 4) + "," + count + " threads created");

        }

    }

    private final class FooWorker implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("in run");
        }
    }

}
```

Why is `count` not incremented ?

Comment: You're also increment `count` only once per 4 `execute` calls.

Comment: Do you see `4,1 threads created` everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are resetting count to 0 each iteration...

```
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter) {

        int count = 0; // count is reset to 0 every loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            es.execute(new FooWorker());
        }

        count = count + 1; // count will always be 1 here
        System.out.println((count * 4) + "," + count + " threads created");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting `count` each time in the outer loop. I am not sure if that's intended.